# rails application helper didn't support chinese characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
  def top_cateogries_with_home(category_id=-1)
    concat(raw "<select name='category_id' id='category_id'>")
    container=[]
    for category in Category.top
      container.push([category.name,category.id])
    end
    concat(raw "<option value='-1' selected>首页</option>")
    concat(raw options_for_select(container, selected = nil))
    concat(raw "</select>")
  end
```

i write a helper method a application_helper.rb,but it will throw issue,if container chinese character 首页,if i replace them with number or other character, it's ok,

i can use comment with chinese character,but if i want to use in helper it throw error,
also in the database's chinse data can display with ror well,

hope someone could help me,thanks

Comment: It is recommended using Ruby 1.9 as soon as you start messing with encodings.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the magic comment `# coding: utf-8` to the beginning of your `application_helper.rb`

It is needed if you are running on Ruby 1.9. You may as well add it to all your `.rb` files

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the problem and exactly the solution. Make sure to put it on line one and include the hash (so it's commented out).