# Rails 3: Read chinese characters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string containing "`系统退信`" but when read, it becomes "`=?gb2312?B?z7XNs83L0MU=?.=`"

How can I compare if the string has those chinese characters?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118391/rails-application-helper-didnt-support-chinese-characters

Answer (score 1):

add this "#encoding:utf-8" in the source file which contains the "系统退信".That should solve the issue

Comment: I did not understand. Care to give an example please?

Comment: if I got a foo.html.erb file which contain something like this "f.lable '系统退信'",then I need to add #encoding:utf-8 into the first line of this file